# Django authentication on home page

Tags: python, django, templates

How can i compare the name of the logged in user on a django home page template with any other string

[this is what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQF12.jpg)

Comment: and share code in question instead posting Screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try like this:

```
{% if user.is_superuser %} // checks if the user is admin
    Admin Dashboard
{% elif user.is_authenticated %}
    Dashboard
{% else %}
    Sign In
{% end %}
```

Here [`is_superuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser) checks if the user is an admin user or not.

Answer (score 0):

to get logged in user details you can do this:

for username `request.user.username`

for first_name `request.user.first_name`

same goes for other values ( fields )